# Processing cube freezes SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2017

We are processing a partition on a cube in latest version of SQL Server 2017 (CU 13, also tried in CU 12 and CU 4) and sometimes it totally freezes. Task manager shows no movement at all - not memory, cpu, nor IO. The only way out is to kill the SSAS process; can't even stop the SSAS service; that is frozen too. We're importing data using M script. There are about 12 tables in the cube, SQL profiler shows 2 of them completed and the rest have starts but no completions. Something is hanging and can't figure out how to debug. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd start by checking to see if there is activity where the source data is located. I've seen it before where SSAS looks to have died but the source databases are getting hit hard with requests so it is actually doing work.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone Thanks for your help but we checked our source databases servers and nothing doing there. It gets stuck for days unless I kill it. With pretty powerful servers I doubt that it's busy in any legitimate way for so long.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is blocked by another process?

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone Thanks again. Unless I'm missing something there are no blocked processes. I used all the techniques mentioned here on all involved servers https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2429/how-to-identify-blocking-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only resolution that we had was to abandon the new connection type that uses "M" and go back to the legacy connection as explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2017/09/12/using-legacy-data-sources-in-tabular-1400/). So far it has not hung.